# SHOUTCast streaming CDN config

Tags: streaming, cdn, shoutcast

Im wonder how to use sc_trans or sc_server to stream in CDN streaming?

Does any of any of you have some working example how to configurate that?

Also will be perfect if you have streamzillacdn example

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you provide more details about what you are specifically trying to do?  Are you just providing an endpoint for the CDN to relay?  If so, there should be nothing more you need to do, outside of a normal server setup.

Comment: Im not setted enpoint.
Can you give some example? :)